# SVG Animating: drawing a line from the center

Tags: css, svg

I have a basic animation that I am wanting to do using an SVG. However I am not 100% sure on how to get it to animate from the center. Being new to SVG animation I know how to make simple ones, but couldn't really find a solid answer to the question I have been having.

```
/*MAIN ANIMATION*/

.line1,
.line2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.line1 {
    top: 0px;
    animation: line1 5s linear forwards; /*ANIMATION NAME AND TIMING*/
}

.line2 {
    bottom: 0px;
    animation: line2 5s linear forwards; /*ANIMATION NAME AND TIMING*/
}

.animationText {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Here is a fiddle for what the lines look like at the moment:
https://jsfiddle.net/7mastya4/6/

So in short I am wanting those lines to animate from the center outwards.
I know how to do standard animation, but being new to SVG and changing their animation origin points it is a bit new to me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't really animate lines with CSS...you need paths...https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: If you see the fiddle, I have made the paths :)

Comment: No...you have `line` elements...not `path`s...but perhaps it will work with lines too.

Comment: Ah I see where u were looking. Dont see why it couldn't as it just a slight reveal. But not too sure yet

Comment: You might try simplifying the code down to just one basic item rather than the large sample you have...it makes it easier to debug and comment.

Comment: `stroke-dashoffset` for `line` elements can be animated using CSS but as far as I know you can't get the *animate from center outwards* effect with it. Instead you can try something like in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/7mastya4/9/).

Comment: @Harry Thanks man. Works perfect

Comment: You're welcome @factordog but my comment was wrong (as proved by Paul's answer).

Comment: @Harry Yes. His version is more simple. But same thing got done differently :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.animline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  -webkit-animation: expand-from-centre 5s linear forwards;
  animation: expand-from-centre 5s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand-from-centre
{
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 300;
    stroke-dashoffset: -150;
  }
  
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 300 300;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}


@keyframes expand-from-centre
{
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 300;
    stroke-dashoffset: -150;
  }
  
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 300 300;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <line class="animline" x1="0" y1="75" x2="300" y2="75"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow, very clever. I didn't think it was possible to get that effect by just animating these two.